# Obtain values before and after string marker?

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain values between two markers and put those values within one row of an array.

Example:

file body:

molecule 1

```
0
1
2
```

molecule 2

```
0
```

molecule 3

```
0
1
...etc
```

I want an array which gives me the following: array = [[0,1,2],[0],[0,1]]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```py
import re
result = []
sub_array = []
with open("7.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line)>0:
            if re.match("\d+", line):
                sub_array.append(line)
            elif len(sub_array)>0:
                result.append(sub_array)
                sub_array = []
    if len(sub_array)>0:
        result.append(sub_array)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, however, I obtain an array which excludes the final molecule, (i.e. molecule 3 --> [0,1]).